# How to directly open the new google sheet created from script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using the following code (after some edits and help from the community here) to create a duplicate sheet from a template sheet. However, the number of sheets have increased now. Is there a way to make some edits in this code such that the newly created sheet shows up directly so I can right away edit without horizontally scrolling through to find the new sheet that was created from the script? .

Edited question for giving better clarity on the issue.

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var oldSheetName = ui.prompt('Sheet to Copy?');
      var newSheetName = ui.prompt('New Sheet Name?');
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(oldSheetName.getResponseText());
      sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(newSheetName.getResponseText()); 
      var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        var p = protections[i];
        var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
        var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
        p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
        p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
        if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
          p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
          p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
          // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
    
            /* Make the new sheet active */
      ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
       }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sheet2.moveActiveSheet(0)
```

this will be the simplest and most effective solution

Comment: Hi, thanks Mike. 

Should I replace " ss.setActiveSheet(sheet); " with the one shared by you??

Comment: yes, try and let me know if it is ok

Comment: Yeah, tried it right after the comment. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: sheet2.moveActiveSheet is not a function"

Comment: Whaaaat, I figured out just by chance to achieve what I want. 

I replaced "ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);" with "ss.setActiveSheet(sheet2);" in the above code that I have shared and it exactly works the way I want it. 

Thank you.

Comment: OK fine! I didn't quite understand what you needed...I expected you would want to go directly to the new tab when opening this spreadsheet in the future